# Why does Java allow to assign a string literal to a String object?

Tags: java, string, oop

String is a class in java. While declaring and assigning string, it is correct to say ***String name = "Paul"*** though to instantiate an object from a java class we do ***String name = new String();*** Taking name as an object, I'm wondering why we can assign a series of characters "Paul" to the object. Under what concept does this one works and how does it?

Comment: It has "special" support from the language itself. Otherwise, you won't be able to do it.

Comment: The [Java Language Specifications, section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) states: _A string literal is always of type String_. That's why this works.

Comment: @zellus: The duplicate does not really answer this question that well, IMO. It doesn't really ask for the difference between them, but why we can do it.

Comment: @jlordo: Do you minds expanding that into an answer? I'll remove my community answer if you do.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Edited your answer :P Was too lazy too start over :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because implicitly Strings - `"..."` are treated as objects as well.

Under the cover JVM looks for similar "objects" in so called `String pool` and then if it finds it there it returns that object (instead of creating new one) otherwise creates new object and puts it to String pool.

This is for memory efficiency, and "Paul" so new String("Paul") is not the same.

This is possible because as we know, strings are immutable in Java.

You can read more about this behavior search for keyword "string pool".

Answer (score 6):

In Java code

```
"Paul"
```

is a String literal and

```
String name
```

a variable of type `String` with the name `name.`

The [Java Language Specifications, section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) states:

> A string literal is always of type `String`

As `123` is an `int` literal and `int number` is a variable of type `int` with the name `number`, following both statements are legal, because the type on the left- and righthand side of the assignments match:

```
int number = 123;
String name = "Paul";
```